# How to bind label in MasterDetailPage and label in ContentPage with the entry from login page?

Tags: xamarin

This is in my Main.xaml.cs (ContentPage):

```
        public string Get_item { get; set; }

        public Main(string SelectedItem)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.BindingContext = this;
        }
```

This is in my MainPage.xaml.cs(MasterDetailPage):

```
 public string Get_item { get; set; }
        public MainPage(string SelectedItem)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Get_item = SelectedItem;
            this.BindingContext = this;

            menuList = new List<MasterPageItem>();
            SetValue(NavigationPage.HasNavigationBarProperty, false);
            // Adding menu items to menuList and you can define title ,page and icon
            menuList.Add(new MasterPageItem() { Title = "Home", Icon = "home_red.png", TargetType = typeof(Main) });
            menuList.Add(new MasterPageItem() { Title = "Settings", Icon = "setting_violet.png", TargetType = typeof(Settings) });           
            menuList.Add(new MasterPageItem() { Title = "LogOut", Icon = "yellow_logout.png", TargetType = typeof(Login) });
            // Setting our list to be ItemSource for ListView in MainPage.xaml
            navigationDrawerList.ItemsSource = menuList;
            // Initial navigation, this can be used for our home page

            Detail = new NavigationPage((Page)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Main)));
        }
```

This is in my MainPage.xaml:

```
<Label Text="{Binding Get_item}" />
```

The label from my MainPage(MasterDetailPage) displays the username after login, this is how I do my login:

```
            var dbpath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "Userdatabase.db");
            var db = new SQLiteConnection(dbpath);
            var loginquery = db.Table<RegUserTable>().Where(u => u.Username.Equals(EntryLoginUsername.Text) && u.Password.Equals(EntryLoginPassword.Text)).FirstOrDefault();

            App.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage(EntryLoginUsername.Text));
```

I want the username to also appear in my Main(ContentPage) but when I login it gives me this error:
System.MissingMethodException: 'Default constructor not found for type App1.Main'

I cant even do this in my MainPage(MasterDetailPage):

```
Detail = new NavigationPage((Page)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Main (EntryLoginUsername.Text)  )));
```

What action would I take so that the username will be present in my ContentPage and MasterDetailPage?

Comment: `Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Main)` requires a default constructor with no parameters

Comment: Hi , when login back to `MainPage` , you can invoke [Application.PageAppearing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.application.pageappearing?view=xamarin-forms) method to update data .

Comment: @Jason is there any way to do that? or change anything?

Comment: create another constructor for your page with no arguments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now already figured out on how Activator.CreateInstance will have params by:

```
Detail = new NavigationPage((Page)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Main), UserLabel.Text));
```

this won't give you an error :D